# How can I debug slow resume from suspend?

Tags: linux, suspend

I have the following issue:
Recently I bought a new laptop, hardware support is good with the exception of the fingerprint reader and some problems with rotation sensors which do not bother me at all. However, there is another problem - when I close the laptop lid and then reopen it after a short time(the system has time to suspend, led indicator starts blinking so I know it is suspended), the system is slow to resume. It shows the image on the screen(what I had opened before), but doesn't accept any input so I have to wait around 5-8 seconds for it to start responding. I think that this is a bug because my previous laptop which had weaker specs(no SSD, older processor, less RAM) used to wake up for about 2-3 seconds. So, how can I debug this? I'm providing links to the output of journalctl -b and dmesg, please tell me if I should provide anything else.(They have the output of two suspend/resume cycles, as the first time I do this it doesn't "hang" for some time, but all subsequent times I try it the problem is present). Note that the system doesn't freeze completely except for the first few seconds.

https://pastebin.com/FBpnmbvD [dmesg output]

https://pastebin.com/11NscmQt [sudo journalctl -b output]